# How to write list to specific location in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

Week over week, I want to be able to write the contents from a list I have to a CSV file. Essentially, I need to find a way to tell Python that if there is content in Column A, write the content in Column B, and so on and so forth because I want to write to the same file week over week. Here is what I have so far.

```
content = [1, 2, 3]
csvfile = "my/file/path"
column = zip(content)
with open(csvfile, 'a') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, dialect = "excel")
    for item in content:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

When I run this twice, my content is appended to the bottom of the column and not a new column. Is my error in my specified mode? W truncates and R is only for reading so I am at a loss.

Here is how it looks when run twice:

```
Column A
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Comment: You need to read the existing file, insert your data in the second column, and then write over the file. csv.writer is just appending like you told it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
content = [1, 2, 3]
csvfile = "my/file/path"
existing = list(csv.reader(open(csvfile))) if os.path.exists(csvfile) else []
#first you have to read in your existing rows/cols
cols = zip(*existing)
#then you transpose it to get your columns
cols.append(content) #add your new content


with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, dialect = "excel")
    for item in zip(*cols): #change columns back to rows
        writer.writerow(item)
```